# Is it possible to run fc without showing my inputted commands?

Tags: bash

If I'm in bash and I type `fc`, write `echo hello world` and save it, it will double print:

```
echo hello world
hello world
```

instead of just

```
hello world
```

Is there any way of avoiding it printing my own commands?

Answer (score 2):

The command to be executed is displayed on `stderr` and so you can remove it by calling

```
fc 2>/dev/null
```

You could make this into a function:

```
fc() { builtin fc "$@" 2>/dev/null; }
```